# use spring to initialize a field in java enum

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have a requirement to initialize the "flag" field in a java enum by spring:

```
public enum EntitySequenceType {
    TypeOne(-1),
    TypeTwo(-1000);
    private boolean flag;

    EntitySequenceType(long firstId){
        System.out.println("enum's constructor: "+this.name()+" firstId="+firstId);
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean val) {
        this.flag = val;
    }

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return this.flag;
    }
}
```

The spring config is:

```
<bean id="myEnum" class="com.maven.start.maven_spring.EntitySequenceType"
        factory-method="valueOf">
    <property name="flag" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>TypeOne</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But I have met some problems, so I have the following questions:

1.It seems that I can only write a single value in the `<constructor-arg>` tag in the config xml, I can't figure out why it is like this.

2.When I debugging the code, I found that when spring is initializing the bean, although I only write one `constructor-arg` value in the config xml, the constructor is called twice.How could this happen?

3.In the constructor of EntitySequenceType, I found that the "flag"'s value is null, why? There is "afterPropertiesSet()" can be called if the enum implements InitializingBean, but it is not called every time a enum type is constructed, so is there any method to be called after the field is set by spring, but is called every time a enum type is called?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This is not how enums work: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that I can only write a single value in the 
>   tag in the config xml, I can't figure out why it is like this.

Used with a `factory-method`, the `constructor-arg` values are referring to the parameter list of that `factory-method`. `EntitySequenceType.valueOf(String)` only takes one argument, a `String`.

> When I debugging the code, I found that when spring is initializing
>   the bean, although I only write one constructor-arg value in the
>   config xml, the constructor is called twice.How could this happen?

Enum types, like any other types, have their `.class` file loaded and initialized when they are first referenced in the code. The `enum` constants

```
TypeOne(-1),
TypeTwo(-1000);
```

are actually `static` fields in the compiled byte code. As such, they are initialized when the class is initialized. Those are two constructor calls, so that is what you see.

The `constructor-arg` value has nothing to do with these constructors, it has to do with your `factory-method`.

> In the constructor of EntitySequenceType, I found that the "flag"'s
>   value is null, why? There is "afterPropertiesSet()" can be called if
>   the enum implements InitializingBean, but it is not called every time
>   a enum type is constructed, so is there any method to be called after
>   the field is set by spring, but is called every time a enum type is
>   called?

It can't be `null`, it's a primitive type. Your property is going to be set after the `factory-method` is called and executed. There is no need to implement `InitializingBean`.

---

Don't use an `enum` for this. Enums are meant to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

> The constructor for an enum type must be **package-private** or **private access**. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself.

Comment: They don't seem to be trying to invoke the constructor themselves.